# How to solve public key is not available error?

Tags: kernel

After the upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04, I cannot update the system. I receive no public key GPG error. I tried to remove the protonvpn but the problem persists. In the Software & Updates there is no repo for protonvpn.

```
$ sudo apt-get update

Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease        
Hit:3 http://ro.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease           
Hit:4 https://repo.protonvpn.com/debian stable InRelease
Hit:5 http://ro.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Err:4 https://repo.protonvpn.com/debian stable InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY <PUBKEY>
Reading package lists... Done
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. **GPG error**: https://repo.protonvpn.com/debian stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY <PUBKEY>
W: Failed to fetch https://repo.protonvpn.com/debian/dists/stable/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY <PUBKEY>
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: It is unclear if you are using ProtonVPN. If so, you should fix the source instead of removing it.

Comment: After I deregistered the protonvpn repo, I am now able to update the system without errors. But the problem now is that when I try to register again the proton vpn repo, it does not appear in the /etc/apt/sources.list, after I run: sudo apt-get update. Therefore neither can I install the app.